# Is this a bad coding style?

Tags: c

I'm currently a freshman (1st semester) studying software engineering. We just did our first assignment in C and my prof told me that I should unlearn this coding style and implied it was unreadable. Is there anything I should change and what is it?

The logic is quite simple, I just typecast the `void*` to a `struct*` corresponding to the passed in enum type in switch cases and perform operations on it, `init` works the same way.

```
#ifndef CORPORATE_H
#define CORPORATE_H
#include "Properties.h"
#define NUM 5

// CORPORATE BLUEPRINT
typedef struct {
    char* _name;
    char* _address;
    APARTMENT apartments[NUM];
    TOWNHOUSE townhouses[NUM];
    SEMI_DETACHED_HOUSE semi_detached_houses[NUM];
} CORPORATE;

// INITIALIZE CORPORATE
void __INIT__(CORPORATE*);

// GET TOTAL EARNINGS OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
double get_monthly_earnings(const CORPORATE*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// GET TOTAL ROI FOR OF PROPERTY TYPE
double get_roi(const CORPORATE*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// GET TOTAL CURRENT VALUE OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
double get_current_value(const CORPORATE*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// GET TOTAL CAPITAL GAINS OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
double get_capital_gains(const CORPORATE*, PROPERTYTYPE);

#endif
```

```
#ifndef PROPERTIES_H
#define PROPERTIES_H
#include "Property_base.h"


// ENUM DATA TYPE FOR PROPERTIES
typedef enum {
    apartment,
    townhouse,
    semi_detached_house
} PROPERTYTYPE;

// APARTMENT BLUEPRINT
typedef struct {
    BASE base;
    double _monthly_condo_fees;
} APARTMENT;


// TOWNHOUSE BLUEPRINT
typedef struct{
    BASE base;
    double _monthly_utilities;
    double _monthly_condo_fees;
    double _monthly_property_tax;
} TOWNHOUSE;


// SEMI-DETACHED HOUSE BLUEPRINT
typedef struct{
    BASE base;
    double _monthly_utilities;
    double _monthly_property_tax;
} SEMI_DETACHED_HOUSE;

// INITIALIZE BASE
void __base_init__(BASE*);

// INITIALIZE PROPERTY OF SPECIFIED TYPE
void __init__(void*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// CALCULATE MONTHLY EARNINGS OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
void cal_monthly_earnings(void*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// CALCULATE ROI OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
void cal_roi(void*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// CALCULATE CURRENT VALUE OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
void cal_current_value(void*, PROPERTYTYPE);

// CALCULATE CAPITAL GAINS OF SPECIFIED PROPERTY TYPE
void cal_capital_gain(void*, PROPERTYTYPE);


#endif
```

Comment: Coding style questions are inherently opinion-based (and therefore off-topic here). Though there are less error prone solutions than passing `void*` around, you might want to read up on "tagged unions"

Comment: This question belongs to CodeReview or SoftwareEngineering rather than here. For sure the technique you are using is unsafe/error prone (I second tagged unions or _Generic from C11); also the naming (e.g. capital letters for types) is far from idiomatic C.

Comment: for future coding reivew questions [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be better place to ask

Comment: `I just typecast the void* to a struct* corresponding to the passed in enum type in switch case` but why not "just" use struct* in the first place? "Just" typecast is doing a lot more then don't typecasting at all.

Comment: Please do not vandalise questions. Especially not if that invalidates answers.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything I should change and what are they

Objective: Do not use identifiers starting with double underscores. `__INIT__` `__init__` `__base_init__` are all reserved identifiers that you can't use.

Almost objective: Do not use upper case identifiers for types. Use lower case. Use upper case only for constants, like `const double PI = 3.14;` or `#define ARRAY_SIZE  20` or `enum { FLAG_A = 10 };`. Let's say all other - lower case (or pascal case or camel case).

`I just typecast the void* to a struct* corresponding to the passed in enum type in switch cases and perform operations on it` - don't. Use and embrace the static type checking built into the language.

Use namespace with functions, where namespace is just a word followed by underscore in function names. Do `base_init(base *t)` or `double propertytype_cal_current_value(propertytype *t)`.

It's really odd that `cal_` function do not return anything. `pow()` calculates a power of anumber, so it returns a number. I would expect `cal_current_value` to return "current value", not `void`.

Also add parameter names in function declarations. Use the same names as in function definitions.

Subjective: align star to the right. `char *stuff` not `char* stuff;`. Put a space before `*` - `void *,` not `void*,`.

Comment: Thank you.beside that, are there anything else? Because they dont make it unreadable do they

Comment: Look at the coding style used by some big projects. Adjust to those, don't invent your own. You will want to work with other people's code, and more importantly, you will want them to want to work with yours.

Comment: there is a base class that has common attributes. cal_ functions just assign the values to them because that was what we were asked to do

Comment: @andy if you want classes - learn C++. OOP in C is just a dirty workaround\

Comment: thanks.Were transitioning to c++ as we move towards the end of the semester

Comment: `there is a base class that has common attributes` Och, I see, so you are implementing a light-weight inheritance. It's going to be _hard_ in C. I suggest to make your functions work on `BASE` anyway, as they work on base. Do `double base_cal_current_value(base *t)` and call it with a pointer to base within the class `base_cal_current_value(&obj.base)`. But indeed, the other way is taking a `void*` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Plenty `void` functions are indications of bad project design. Especially if even function name shows that you want to return something (`cal_monthly_earnings`)
2. Do not try to be too "generic". Avoid `void` pointers unless they are absolutely needed. It will hide potential warnings and makes code very difficult to debug and maintain.
3. I personally prefer `semiDetachedHouse` style variable names instead of underscores.
4. Avoid as you would the plague side effects (ie modifying objects passed as a pointer). Use them only when it is absolutely necessary.
5. I personally prefer types to have some special suffix. For example `myData_type` (here I use underscore)